# Restrict Blocks in ContentArea

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I'm having a issue restricting what kind of Block to be inserted in a ContentArea. What I want is that the SliderBlock's ContentArea property can only have insertion of a SlideItemBlock.

```
[ContentType(...)]
public class SlideItemBlock : BlockData
{
    [Required]
    Display(Name = "Image")]
    public virtual string Image { get; set;}
}

[ContentType(...)]
public class SliderBlock : BlockData
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Slides")]
    public virtual ContentArea Slides { get; set; }
    //Should only accept insertion of SlideItemBlock
}
```

Or is this the wrong way to achive what I'm trying to restrict for the editor to not drag and drop wrong block types?

As of now, I can create a SliderBlock and insert a SlideItemBlocks in it. If I then insert the created SliderBlock in a new SliderBlock I get a forever and ever loop and It breaks the site. This is what I'm trying to control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you´re using EPiServer 7.5 restricting which blocks you can use in a content area is built in. For details take a look at this blog post: [Restricting the allowed types in a content area](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2013/11/Restricting-the-allowed-types-in-a-content-area/).

Code example from the blog post:

```
  [EditorDescriptorRegistration(TargetType = typeof(ContentArea), UIHint = "Gallery")]
  public class ImageGalleryEditorDescriptor : EditorDescriptor
  {    
     public ImageGalleryEditorDescriptor()    
     {    
        // Setup the types that are allowed to be dragged and dropped into the content        
        // area; in this case only images are allowed to be added.        
        AllowedTypes = new Type[] { typeof(IContentImage) };         

        // Unfortunetly the ContentAreaEditorDescriptor is located in the CMS module        
        // and thus can not be inherited from; these settings are copied from that        
        // descriptor. These settings determine which editor and overlay should be        
        // used by this property in edit mode.        
        ClientEditingClass = "epi-cms.contentediting.editors.ContentAreaEditor";        
        OverlayConfiguration.Add("customType", "epi-cms.widget.overlay.ContentArea");    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

As of EpiServer 8 theres a new attribute called [AllowedTypes].  This is now the best way of restricting blocks.  It overcomes a lot of the limitations of [AvailableContentTypes].  When you drag blocks into a content area the validation actually works.

An example code snippet would be

```
[AllowedTypes(new []{ typeof(SlideBlock) })]
public virtual ContentArea Slides { get; set; }
```

Theres a good code example here [How To Restrict The Blocks Allowed Within A Content Area Episerver](http://jondjones.com/how-to-restrict-the-blocks-allowed-within-a-content-area-episerver/)

Also this one on EpiWorld http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2015/2/the-new-and-improved-allowed-types/

Answer (score 1):

Of you have not upgraded to 7.5 yet as Frederik suggest we have the following attribute we have created to do just this.

```
using EPiServer.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace xxx.Com.Core.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class OurAvailableContentTypesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public Type[] Include { get; set; }
        public Type[] Exclude { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!(value is ContentArea))
            {
                throw new ValidationException("OurAvailableContentTypesAttribute is intended only for use with ContentArea properties");
            }

            var contentArea = value as ContentArea;

            var notAllowedcontentNames = new List<string>();

            if (contentArea != null)
            {
                if (Include != null)
                {
                    var notAllowedContent = contentArea.Contents.Where(x => !ContainsType(Include, x.GetType()));
                    if (notAllowedContent.Any())
                    {
                        notAllowedcontentNames.AddRange(notAllowedContent.Select(x => string.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.ContentLink.ID)));
                    }
                }
                if (Exclude != null)
                {
                    var notAllowedContent = contentArea.Contents.Where(x => ContainsType(Exclude, x.GetType()));
                    if (notAllowedContent.Any())
                    {
                        notAllowedcontentNames.AddRange(notAllowedContent.Select(x => string.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.ContentLink.ID)));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (notAllowedcontentNames.Any())
            {
                ErrorMessage = "contains invalid content items :";
                foreach (var notAllowedcontentName in notAllowedcontentNames)
                {
                    ErrorMessage += " " + notAllowedcontentName + ",";
                }
                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage.TrimEnd(',');

                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private bool ContainsType(Type[] include, Type type)
        {
            return include.Any(inc => inc.IsAssignableFrom(type));
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var result = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
            if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ErrorMessage))
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = string.Format("{0} {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, ErrorMessage);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

the usage of this is then

```
public class OurBlock : BlockData
    {
        [CultureSpecific]
        [Editable(true)]
        [Display(Name = "",
            Description = "",
            GroupName = SiteConstants.GroupNames.ContentArea,
            Order = 1)]
        [OurAvailableContentTypes(Include = new[] { typeof(OurImageBlock)  })]
        public virtual ContentArea ImageContentArea { get; set; }
```

HTH

Adam

Comment: Shouldn't you use the AllowedTypes annotation in Epi 7.5 instead? Seems to do the same thing

Comment: @EricHerlitz which is why my suggestion started with the premise that the OP hadn't yet upgraded to 7.5 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a validation class and implement the IValidate interface from EPiServer.validation. The validation of this is kept outside of the PageData and BlockData classes.

This should be what you are looking for

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using EPiServer.Validation;

public class SliderBlockValidator : IValidate<SliderBlock>
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(SliderBlock instance)
    {
        var errors = new List<ValidationError>();
        if (instance.Slides != null &&
            instance.Slides.Contents.Any(x => x.GetType().BaseType != typeof (SlideItemBlock)))
        {
            errors.Add(new ValidationError()
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Only SlideItemBlocks are allowed in this area",
                    PropertyName = "Slides",
                    Severity = ValidationErrorSeverity.Error,
                    ValidationType = ValidationErrorType.StorageValidation
                });
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```

More reading at http://sdkbeta.episerver.com/SDK-html-Container/?path=/SdkDocuments/CMS/7/Knowledge%20Base/Developer%20Guide/Validation/Validation.htm&vppRoot=/SdkDocuments//CMS/7/Knowledge%20Base/Developer%20Guide/

If you have upgraded to EPi 7.5 you can use the AllowedTypes annotation

```
[AllowedTypes(new [] {typeof(SlideItemBlock)})]
public virtual ContentArea Slides { get; set; }
```

I am unaware if you are able to customize any messages using the later solution. There are a few known limitations

- Restriction does not work for overlays when editing on page. This is a bug that has been fixed and will be released in a patch in a few weeks.
- **No server validation.** Currently, the attribute only adds restriction in the UI. We hope to be able to add support for server validation soon which would also give the posibility validate your custom properties.
- **No validation when creating local blocks in content areas.** If you use the new feature to add local blocks to a content area, there is currently no filtering of the content types when you create your new block.

Read more at http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2013/12/Restriction-of-content-types-in-properties/

All in all the first solution is currently the better one.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a validation attribute to the content area property to restrict the allowed block types. 
See [this link](http://www.menzies-smith.co.uk/?p=76) for a detailed example.

Then using the AvailableContentTypes attribute you can restrict to only allow SlideItemBlock types.

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Slides")]
    [AvailableContentTypes(Include = new []{typeof(SlideItemBlock)})]
    public virtual ContentArea Slides { get; set; }
```